# How can I add parameters automatically in my call of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision

I'm beginner and I'm making a little game in js/jquery.

I made some enemies spawning every X seconds (and getting an unique id) which go cross the window. Then **I wanted to make some collision with the spaceship** I made. The problem I got here is that everytime one enemy spawn the collision with the previous enemies is not possible (**collision is possible only with the last spawned enemy**) so I wondered if I make a function creating a line  calling the collision function everytime an enemy spawn it will work :/

```
function newEnemy(enemyId) {
    var imgElement = $('<img>', {
    src: 'enemy.png',
    id: 'enemy' + enemyId,
    }
return { // Object containing properties of an enemy
    id: enemyId,
}

$(function(){ //make enemies appear
     setInterval(function() {     
        var id = ++enemyIdCounter;
        var baddie = newEnemy(id);
        enemies[id] = baddie;
        $(document.body).append(baddie.img);

    setInterval(function() { // move of an enemy
```

You can ignore this code (just if you wonder what I did under this)
The last setInterval(function(){ ... },20); contains the next code

```
function collision($ship, $baddie) {
    var x1 = $ship.offset().left;
    var y1 = $ship.offset().top;
    var h1 = $ship.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $ship.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $baddie.offset().left;
    var y2 = $baddie.offset().top;
    var h2 = $baddie.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $baddie.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is the actual line making collision with only the last enemy

```
    $('#result').text(collision($('#ship'), $('#enemy' + baddie.id)));
```

Here is what I tried but didn't work (certainly because I did it bad)
So here is the problem from the title of this post how can I add the second parameters automatically and how to write it correctly

```
    $('#result').text(collision($('#ship'), $('#enemy1')));
    $('#result').text(collision($('#ship'), $('#enemy2')));
    $('#result').text(collision($('#ship'), $('#enemy3')));
    $('#result').text(collision($('#ship'), $('#enemy4')));
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your first code sample is full of errors, missing `}` extra `,` etc... is that code fine of your-end?

Comment: Yea in fact I didn't wrote everything so that's why there is extra     ,    and for the     }     they are lower in my code I should have put them :/ sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of enemies already `enemies[]`.

To check the collision with them all, just do:

```
 var hasCollided = false;
 $.each(enemies, function(index, value) {
     hasCollided = (hasCollided || collision($('#ship'), value.img)));
 });
 $('#result').text(hasCollided);
```

Remember to remove enemies from `enemies[]` array when they are destroyed.

Comment: enemies is supposed to be an array with 'enemy' + id of each enemies created ? Am I not supposed to push each enemies to the array ?
(I tried this code but didn't work but thanks for showing me the way to do it)

Comment: Your enemies array have the elements already, doesn't it? I have just updated it. You are pushing new baddies objects with img elements.

Comment: my `enemies[id] = baddie;` seems like doing nothing, I tried to
`setInterval(function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
                        $('#debug').text(enemies);
                    }
                },500);`
(sorry for the code it's just to see what the array contains everytime an enemy is created
So I created 
`enemy = new Array;
enemy.push('#enemy' + baddie.id);`
and the setInterval + for worked for enemy
maybe should I use this array ? I'm really disturbed by the enemies array

Comment: Is it possible that you could put your code in a jsfiddle? It would be easier for me to understand what odd behavior you are dealing with.

Comment: Sure I'm doing it (first time I do that just need a little minute) jsfiddle.net/kodoyosa/ho67t5tb/3 I didn't succeed to put the images if you need it I'll upload them.

Oh btw be careful there is nothing to stop the spawn of the enemies for the moment ^^'

Comment: @Kodoyosa I just had time to analyze your code now. Now that I understand the purpose of the `#result`, I had to change the code. You need to know if any of all ships has collided. Also, you are using too much timers. Try to group them all into one, and the collision on the end of it. If you separate the collision time to the ship moving time, make sure you do a collision test on the end of both.